# How do i write a regex for capturing decimal numbers?

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that will capture all of the following numbers from a sample text:

```
2.5
5
0.2
.5
```

Assuming its not going to be more than 2 digits on either side of the decimal point, what regex do i use?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This regex will do the job (i.e. no more than 2 digits on either side of the decimal point)

```
^(?:\d{0,2}\.\d{1,2})$|^\d{1,2}$
```

**explanation:**

```
^               # Begining of the string
  (?:           # begining of NON capture group
    \d{0,2}     # matches 0,1 or 2 digits
    \.          # decimal point
    \d{1,2}     # 1 or 2 digits
  )             # end of non capture group
$               # end of string

|               # OR

^               # Begining of the string
  \d{1,2}     # 1 or 2 digits
$               # end of string
```

This regex will match:
`2.5, 5, 0.2, .5`
but not:
`123.456, 256`

Answer (score 23):

This should work.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)
```

It means

- `(` begin capture group
- `\d*` any digit zero or more times
- `\.?` a period zero or one times (i.e. it is optional)
- `\d+` any digit one ore more times
- `)` end capture group

It will match all the number you listed and capture them in `$1`.

Comment: You can remove the parentheses and use `$0` to get the match contents of the entire regex.

Comment: This will match `123.456` but the OP wants no more than 2 digits on either side of the decimal point.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the tip. i forgot about `$0` since i tend to find that i usually only want to capture a portion of regex.

Comment: @M42 I suppose I read that differently than you did. I read it as saying that the input will never have more than 2 digits on either side of the decimal. Ill add a second regex to clarify.

Comment: @Jeff: You're probably rigth as the OP has accepted the answer :-)

Comment: @Jeff: :( sorry for accepting your answer, M42's does suit my purpose better.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html